# What does the new Facebook Connect platform offer over a traditional Facebook App?

Tags: facebook

[Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php) seems like the cool new way to leverage a user's Facebook account on your own site (get their friends list, write to their profile, etc).  What I don't understand is what the new Facebook Connect platform offers over a traditional Facebook App with the Offline Access permission granted.

Can anyone help me out by providing a clear explanation of the differences between the two options?  When would it be better to use one over the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Facebook connect appears to be designed for integration with sites not accessed through Facebook, but sites that are existing outside of facebook, and using facebook as an integration method.

I see it as being a really different way of doing things, if you want facebook integration on your OWN site, Facebook Connect is the way to go.  If you want to build an application to work inside facebook, the current method is the way to go.